# Access Setting Theme VBA using MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex is off by 1

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365, themes

When setting a control/form theme, I often use VBA, as I can change the color on the fly. Works great. I have been trying to move my Database away from using hard-coded numbers, and built up a theme module that is included which has themes mapped so I could just change them there instead of everywhere else.

Then I realized, hey, there's an easier way to do this (or...so I thought).
Enter [Enums `MsoThemeColorIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msothemecolorindex) and [`MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msothemecolorschemeindex). This way, I can even do fancy things like decide that when I use `myInternalTheme1` constant, I could just switch it out with `MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex.msoThemeAccent1`.

A long while back I noticed that if I used what is shown on the help docs (above), the themes were "off" by 1. Namely `5` (`msoThemeAccent1` "Theme1"), instead of mapping to `msoThemeAccent1` actually maps to "Theme2", and "Theme 2" Color is displayed. So, I just manually adjusted. But I'm wondering if I'm missing something here, and I'm using the value incorrectly?

I've used SaveAsText to export these forms after saving the values, and when I do, the field that's had "Theme 1" manually applied in Properties shows that the value `4` is used, which "should" map to `msoThemeColorLight2`, but doesn't.

Field's Backtheme setting:

```
BackThemeColorIndex =4
```

How I'm using this:

```
    ' In my "modColor" 

    Public Const MythemeAccent1 As Integer = 4 ' (help docs specify this as MsoThemeColorIndex.msoThemeColorLight2)

    ' This one colors the header in Theme2 "wrong color, correct enum value???" 
    ' MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex.msoThemeAccent1 = 5 (as docs say)
    Me.section(acHeader).BackThemeColorIndex = MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex.msoThemeAccent1 

    ' This one colors the header with Theme1 "correct color, wrong enum value???"
    '  MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex.msoThemeLight2 = 4 (as docs say)
    Me.section(acHeader).BackThemeColorIndex = MsoThemeColorSchemeIndex.msoThemeLight2

'  my internal module, this works correctly (code looks correct, and correct color used).
    Me.section(acHeader).BackThemeColorIndex = MythemeAccent1
```

If I assign the color in Design View via `Form Properties > FormHeader > Format > Back Color > "Accent 1"` it works correctly, and the theme is properly applied.

[FormHeader Properties Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoX5y.png)

I've verified the theme is correct, numerous times. I exported the theme, and verified that the XML for "Accent 1" is correct, and that "Accent2" is different. "Theme 1" is "Bluish" and "Theme 2" is "Redish" for reference, so it's not like my monitor rendering is just making me think it's different.

Excerpted XML from `.Thmx` file:

```
           <a:accent1>
                <a:srgbClr val="5C83B4"/>
            </a:accent1>
            <a:accent2>
                <a:srgbClr val="E74B4B"/>
            </a:accent2>
```